# Writing numbers into a file- check code

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing

I'm taking my first ever CS class and I have an assignment due Friday.
I just wanted someone to check my code and make sure it works/follows the directions.

Instructions:

**Write a program that:**

1) gets the name of a text file of numbers from the user.  Each number in the file is on its own line.

2) reads in those numbers one at a time

3) writes the even numbers to a file named even.txt

4) writes the odd numbers to a file named odd.txt

5) displays to the user the sum of the positive numbers and the count of the negative numbers.

**HERE IS WHAT I HAVE**

```
def main():

    #Open text file for reading
    numberFile = open(r'numberFile.txt', 'r')

#Priming read
    number = numberFile.readline()

#Setting up loop to continue reading until
#an empty line is reached
    total = 0
    count = 0
    while number != '':
        number = float(number)                  #convert from string to number
        if number%2 == 0:                       
            evenNumber = open('even.txt', 'w')  #writes even numbers into a file
            evenNumber.write(number + '\n')
        else:
            oddNumber  = open('odd.txt', 'w')   #writes odd numbers into a file
            oddNumber.write(number + '\n')

        for number in numberFile:
            number = float(number)      #convert from string to number

            if number <= 0:             #identify negative numbers
                count +=1               #count negative numbers

            if number >= 0:             #identify positive numbers
                total += number           #sum of positive numbers
        number = numberFile.readline()

    numberFile.close()                  #close file after program is complete
main()
```

Comment: SO is not a code review or homework revision site. If there is a problem with your code, indicate specifically what is not working by showing the invalid output or error code and provide an explanation of what your expected output is.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask *is* a codereview site, though

Comment: @WayneWerner But they still expect you to ask specific questions, not just post a bunch of code.

Comment: Isn't this what the teacher will do when they grade the assignment? Why do you need us to do their job?

Comment: @Barmar presumably the OP wants to get a good grade on the assignment and is looking for help from people who more than likely were there at some point in history.

Comment: Is zero a negative number? For sure you could just do `if number > 0` for the total, though, since `total += 0` won't alter the total.

Comment: you should open the `odd` and `even` file outside the loop and close then at the end

Comment: ".. make sure it works" - you can test that part yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't a code review site, I'll give you some pointers.

1. You never get a filename from the user - you should probably add that. It will be something like `filename = input('Enter filename: ')`
2. You overwrite the `even.txt` and `odd.txt` each time you open it with `'w'`. Consider using `'a+'`
3. You never output the `total` or the `count`. Try using `print` on those.

On top of all of that, there are better ways to open files are do those kinds of operations, but I'll let you learn those in a future class.